# How to interface a scanner to a google spreadsheet?

Tags: interface, spreadsheet

I am trying to build a Asset Manager. I am using a scanner or a mobile device to scan the barcode which is the asset id. My requirement is as follows:
1) When the scanner scans for the first time the data(purchase date, cost, assigned to , history) should be allowed to be entered and the data should be stored in the google spreadsheet.
2) When the product or the item is already present it should display me the result(purchase date, cost, assigned to , history).

It would be a great help if i get a clue on what could be done.
Thanks in advance.
Mithun

Answer (score 0):

Things you may consider:

1. What protocal to use to interface with the device. For example, I would recommend TWAIN for scanners.
2. What's your app type? Is it a web one that you can do scanning from browsers? Then you can choose the according scanning  SDK for your project.
3. Store data to Google Spreadsheet. [This post](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps-script/pie8B-KnKsY) might help.

Comment: Hi Rachel, Thanks for providing me inputs of how to go about the application , i want the application to be web based . Storing the data looks to be fine. But wha about retrieving the data from the google spreadsheet, if the scanner scans the product barcode already present it should be able to get me the result from the google drive  how can i achieve that?

Comment: You can check the link here: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get